# Invalid Argument = Value of "0" is not valid for index Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

With a button click i'm trying to check existing rows in the listview.

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button8.Click
    If ListViewExtended1.Items.Count >= 0 Then
        timer_firstROW.Enabled = True
    Else
        timer_firstROW.Enabled = False
    End If
    If ListViewExtended1.Items.Count >= 1 Then
        timer_SecondRow.Enabled = True
    Else
        timer_SecondRow.Enabled = False
    End If
    If ListViewExtended1.Items.Count >= 2 Then
        Timer_ThirdRow.Enabled = True
    Else
        Timer_ThirdRow.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

So if there is no item with index 1 or 2, i have an error. 
I know that its common problem, but im really cant get why "if - end if " statements cause that error. Because as i'm understand if there is not one of the items, compiler just make timer enabled = false ,and goes to next statement.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown by that code?

Comment: The code that you have shown is certainly not the code that raised the exception. Post the stacktrace. You will notice that it also shows the line where the error was raised, add that code too